# Python C# datatypes for Sockets

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, casting

I am creating a socket server to connect and speak with a C# program over TCP. Currently I am trying to create a way to convert the hex sent over the TCP socket to specific variables (the variable type will be in the packet header, and yes I do know tcp is a stream not technically sending packets but I am designing it like this). Currently I have all of the C# integral numeric types converting to and from bytesarray/integers correctly via the code below (All of the different types are the same with a couple edits to fit the c# type)

```
## SBYTE Type Class definition
## C#/Unity "sbyte" can be from -128 to 127
##
## Usage:
##
## Constructor
## variable = sbyte(integer)
## variable = sbyte(bytearray)
## 
## Variables
## sbyte.integer (Returns integer representation)
## sbyte.bytes (Returns bytearray representation)

class sbyte:

    def __init__(self, input):
        if type(input) == type(int()):
            self.integer = input
            self.bytes = self.__toBytes(input)
        elif type(input) == type(bytearray()):
            self.bytes = input
            self.integer = self.__toInt(input)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"sbyte constructor can take integer or bytearray type not {type(input)}")
                

    ## Return Integer from Bytes Array
    def __toInt(self, byteArray):
        ## Check that there is only 1 byte
        if len(byteArray) != 1:
            raise OverflowError(f"sbyte.__toInt length can only be 1 byte not {len(byteArray)} bytes")

        ## Return signed integer
        return int.from_bytes(byteArray, byteorder='little', signed=True)


    ## Return Bytes Array from Integer
    def __toBytes(self, integer):

        ## Check that the passed integer is not larger than 128 and is not smaller than -128
        if integer > 127 or integer < -128:
            raise ValueError(f"sbyte.__toBytes can only take an integer less than or equal to 127, and greater than or equal to -128, not \"{integer}\"")

        ## Convert the passed integer to Bytes
        return integer.to_bytes(1, byteorder='little', signed=True)
```

This is working for all the types I currently implemented, but I do wonder if there is a better way to handle this? Such as using ctype's or some other python library. Since this will be a socket server with potentially many connections handling this as fast as possible is best. Or if there is anything else you see that I can improve I would love to know.

Comment: Are you really sending _hex_ over the socket (i.e. ASCII characters in the range 0-9a-f), or raw bytes?

Comment: And if you want things to be fast, don't roll your own serialization/deserialization; use e.g. Msgpack, BSON, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is an integer value from a byte array, simply index the byte array:

```
>>> b = bytearray.fromhex('1E')
>>> b[0]
30
```

Comment: For some unsigned types that will work but I don't think that will work for signed types. Such as sbyte's in the example. For example if you do fromhex('F3') then b[0] it will won't be a signed byte and instead return 243. Unless there is another way to do this? Although for unsigned types I will test that really quick and see if it is faster than struct.

Comment: If you want to make it signed, subtract 127.

Comment: If I do bytearray.fromhex('F3')[0] it returns 243, if you subtract 127 that is 116. A C# sbyte of hex 'F3' would return -13.

Comment: Sorry, I meant subtract 256.

Comment: This kind of works but for example hex 7F of a signed byte should equal 127. Instead it initially return 127 which is correct but if you subtract 256 then I get -129. I can do a check to see if the value is over 127 then subtract 256. I am testing that now with timeit. If it is the fastest I will mark your answer!

Comment: Tested it with the others via timeit and it is the fastest by a slight margin! Thanks for the input I think I need to test each cast for each type individually between the different methods to find the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

After testing the differenced between from_bytes, struct.unpack, and numpy.frombuffer with the following code:

```
setup1 = """\
byteArray = bytearray.fromhex('1E')
"""

setup2 = """\
import struct
byteArray = bytearray.fromhex('1E')
"""

setup3 = """\
import numpy as np
type = np.dtype(np.byte)
byteArray = bytearray.fromhex('1E')
"""

stmt1 = "int.from_bytes(byteArray, byteorder='little', signed=True)"
stmt2 = "struct.unpack('b', byteArray)"
stmt3 = "np.frombuffer(byteArray, type)"

print(f"First statement execution time = {timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt1, setup=setup1, number=10**8)}")
print(f"Second statement execution time = {timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt2, setup=setup2, number=10**8)}")
print(f"Third statement execution time = {timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt3, setup=setup3, number=10**8)}")
```

**Results:**

```
First statement execution time = 14.456886599999999
Second statement execution time = 6.671141799999999
Third statement execution time = 21.8327342
```

From the initial results it looks like struct is the fastest way to accomplish this. Unless there are other libraries I am missing.

**EDIT:**

Per AKX's suggestion I added the following test for signed byte:

```
stmt4 = """\
if byteArray[0] <=127:
    byteArray[0]
else:
    byteArray[0]-127
"""
```

and got the following execution time:

```
Fourth statement execution time = 4.581732600000002
```

Going this path is the fastest although slightly over just using structs. I will have to test with each type for the fastest way to cast the bytes and vice versa but this question gave me 4 different ways to test each one now. Thanks!